# $(n-1)$-dimensional subspace of an $n$-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f$ be a fixed nonzero linear functional on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ and 
>   $H=\{\alpha \in V:f(\alpha)=0\}$. Then $H$ is a subspace of $V$ and its dimension is $n-1$.

I have shown that $H$ is a subspace of $V$. Do you have an idea how to show that its dimension is $n-1$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Idea: Associate $f$ with it's dual inside the vector space and consider it as a basis vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\dim (\ker(f))+ \dim(\operatorname{Im}(f)) = \dim V=n$ your $H=\ker(f)$ and $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(f))=1$

Comment: Why is it that $dim(Im(f))=1$?

Comment: Because a non-zero linear functional is **always** onto...prove this.

Comment: $f:V\to\Bbb R$, it takes a nonzero value, so it is going to be surjective as DonAntonio wrote, and $\dim\Bbb R=1$.

Comment: What if our field of definition is not the set of real numbers?say a field $F$. Then $f:V\to F$ and so $dim(Im(f))=dim(F)$. Will it follow that $dim(F)=1$?

Comment: Any field is a 1-dimensional vector space over itself...I have this feeling that you should perhaps go over the basics of vector space theory, in particular because it is going to get tougher later to follow stuff without the basic well understood.

Comment: You're right DOnAntonio, I should go over the basics of Vector Space theory. This explains why the above equality holds. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Here a complete proof. Suppose that $f:V\rightarrow F$  nonzero linear functional on an n-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field $F$.
We know that $f(V)=\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is a subspace of $F$ so $0\leq\dim\, \operatorname{Im}(f)\leq \dim F =1$. But $\dim\, \operatorname{Im}(f)\neq 0$ because $f$ is a nonzero linear functional so $\dim\, \operatorname{Im}(f)=1$ and then $Im(f)=F$ i.e. $f$ is surjective. Now by rank–nullity theorem we have as jim did:
$$\dim (\ker(f))+ \dim(\operatorname{Im}(f)) = \dim V=n$$ with $H=\ker(f)$ so $\dim H=n-1$.